# how to redirect URL using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, redirect

I need to redirect this URL: http://www.africafreak.com/blog/sitemap.xml into http://africafreak.com/blog/sitemap.xml using .htaccess file

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

If your website is hosted on an apache server, a redirect from www to non-www is a simple implementation. Add the following to your .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

or try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi frnd, this url http://www.africafreak.com/sitemap.xml is getting redirecting into this http://africafreak.com/sitemap.xml. But this url http://www.africafreak.com/blog/sitemap.xml is not getting redirecting to this http://africafreak.com/blog/sitemap.xml by using ur code